# Assembly present in the GAC but system found it only when copied to local directory. Why?

Tags: .net, gac, .net-assembly

I had a situation similar to the one detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394106/gac-assembly-is-in-the-gac-but-could-not-load-file-or-assembly), which has an excellent solution to it too. 
    The way I got around my error is different from the one in the post. I am not sure why it fixed the issue. I am very curious to understand why.

My situation - I had a native 32-bit assembly A.exe which was loading System.Data and System.Data was in turn loading System.Numerics. The 'Cannot load assembly' happened with System.Numerics. The System.Numerics assembly was present in the GAC and I ensured using fusion log viewer that the public key token of the expected assembly and the one in the GAC matched. But fusion logs would still say that GAC lookup was unsuccessful.

The issue went away when I copied the System.Numerics assembly from the GAC location into the directory of A.exe. I am curious why this fixed the issue and why the GAC lookup was unsuccessful.

Comment: Could it be a 32/64 bit issue? or a versioning issue, where you are using version 1.0 (for example) but it requires version 1.1. The logs would be useful in diagnosing further.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing on a **64bit** machine and using "**Use Any CPU**" on any of the projects in the solution it will by default, load GAC assemblies that are **64bit**. To avoid this, you set all your projects to compile using **32bit only**. That way, only the 32bit GAC will be used.